# convert a pygame surface into an image?

Tags: python, pygame

is there a way to convert a pygame surface into a png image?

```
rgb_content = pygame.surfarray.array2d(canvas)
cv2.imwrite(file, rgb_content, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work, because it flips the image sideways. Makes it grayscale and doesn't actually save it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`save`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save) function of the `image` modul:

> `pygame.image.save()`
> *save an image to disk*
> `save(Surface, filename) -> None`
>
> This will save your Surface as either a BMP, TGA, PNG, or JPEG image. If the filename extension is unrecognized it will default to TGA. Both TGA, and BMP  file formats create uncompressed files.

So just use it like this:

```
pygame.image.save(your_surface, "your_filename.png")
```